# How to select records that fall between a start and end time?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on an application that will reserve conference rooms and need a little assistance with my query.  When the user selects a date and start and end time, I do an ajax call to query the database to see if there are any conference rooms available during that time range on that date.  This obviously means all the various possibilities (starts before requested start time and ends after the requested end time, starts after the requested start time and ends before requested end time, etc.)

I am trying to do something like:

```
SELECT room_id From table where ( 
(start_time >= request_start and end_time <= request_end) 
or 
(start_time <= request_start and end_time >= request_end)
or
(start_time >= request_start and end_time <= request_end)
or
(start_time <= request_start and end_time >= request_end)
)
```

However the above does not seem to work.  Obviously I do not need/want rooms that fall outside of the requested time (both start and end before the requested start and end or both start and end after the requested start and end). But I do need those that start before the request start, but end before the requested end and start after the request start and end after the request end.

The logic seems to be eluding me.  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Also, on a side note, I want to return the room_ids that are reserved because the above is a sub query that I used to select room_ids that are not in the returned list result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this blog post](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.co.uk/search/label/overlap) for an explanation, the condition to use is simply:

```
where request_end >= start_time
and   request_start <= end_time
```

Comment: `a>=b and b<=a ==> a=b`. you probably ment `where request_end >= start_time and request_start <= end_time`

Comment: Tony, thanks for the answer and the link to the blog.  While the explanation makes sense it does not seem to work for me.  Using the above I do not get what I would expect.  Here is a sample circumstance: Room A 11:15-12:45 and Room B 10:30 - 11:30.  Request time 11:00 - 11:30.  Using the above I get room B returned, even though Room A should also be returned.  I must be missing something, but I am not seeing it.

Comment: @wblakenc Room A is not available until 11:15 but the request needs it at 11:00.

Comment: Griffey,  Room A is booked from 11:15 to 12:45 and Room B is booked from 10:30 to 11:30 so when I run the query to find booked rooms shouldn't both A and B return?  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @wblakenc, my conditions will return both A and B, so there must be something different with your version of it.  Maybe you can post the SQL you ran?

Comment: @TonyAndrews, thanks for your continued assitance.  Here is the query:`select location_id
from request r join event_schedule es on es.request_id = r.id 
where (to_timestamp('Mar 23 2012 12:00:00', 'mon dd yyyy hh24:mi:ss') >= start_time and to_timestamp('Mar 23 2012 11:00:00', 'mon dd yyyy hh24:mi:ss') <= end_time);` The one thing to note (not that I am sure it matters, but the start and end time are timestamps (hence the conversion).  When I run the above query I should get both A and B, but I only get B.

Comment: @TonyAndrews, I figured it out.  My problem was something silly I did when testing different times.  In the DB I had Room A reserved from 11:15 AM to 12:45AM (on the same day). Either way, once I fixed the timestamp in the DB to PM instead of AM all became well with the world.  Thanks again!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think i will work for your Problem

((\"TIMESTART\"  BETWEEN '"+startTime+"'  AND '"+endTime+"') OR (\"ENDTIME\"  BETWEEN '"+startTime+"'  AND '"+endTime+"'))";